# diff'ing *.so or *.a

Tags: gcc, diff, .a, .so

I'm guessing there's a time stamp inside a *.so which causes a "diff" to show the same file built hours apart, with no source change, as different.

Is there a way to diff *.so, *.a, and *.la files and ignore the time stamp?

Comment: Just cut off the header and diff the rest?  Is the difference appearing at a predictable offset?

Comment: Note also that "no source change" does not guarantee that the compiler sees the same code, due to makefile rules, preprocessor macros `__TIME__` and `__DATE__`, etc.

Comment: "Just cut off the header and diff the rest?"  How do you do that?

Comment: dd command has a skip= parameter. With that you can make a copy of the file starting after the header.